# 'element not interactable' exception in C# chromedriver

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am using selenium chromedriver in c# to try and click a print button however I am receiving an exception of "element not interactable", here is the website source of the print button:

```
<p _ngcontent-c27="" class="print"><span _ngcontent-c27="" class="floatRight">Print</span><img _ngcontent-c27="" class="printImg" src="../../../../../assets/images/Print.svg"></p>
```

What I've tried:

```
driver.FindElementById("clippedTab").Click(); // Successfully clicks on the 'Clipped' tab

//None of the below worked:

driver.FindElementByClassName("print").Click();
// and
driver.FindElementByClassName("printImg").Click();
// and
driver.FindElementByClassName("floatRight").Click();
```

However none of these worked for me.

The website used is [bjs.com](https://www.bjs.com/myCoupons?source=header) and the print button and can be found on the `Clipped` tab.

What am I doing wrong, why is the element not intractable and how could I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Xpath you are making is actually causing issue.

All the above Xpaths are not unique and actually point to 2 Xpaths 1 is Print you want to click, and other is not interactable(or hidden) one. Since it is trying to click on hidden one, it is throwing Error.
See image
[image]

Simple solution  :- use XPath as :: `//*@id="clipped"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/p/span`

Comment: I get an error: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='clipped']/div/div1/div[3]/div/p/span"}

Comment: I found out the problem, the correct xPath would be:
//*[@id='clipped']/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/p/span

Comment: Once you edit your answer, I'll mark it as a solution, thanks!

Comment: Well i added the same.. but it took it as a link.. edited now

Answer (score 0):

The element has to be visible (that's usually what makes it "interactable") before you can Click() it. Are you opening the "Clipped" tab before you Click()?

Comment: Yes, I use this code which successfully clicks on the tab:
driver.FindElementById("clippedTab").Click(); however it fails to click the print button.

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to `Click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("img.printImg"))).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//img[@class='printImg']/h2"))).Click();
  ```